# How to Map array Of Json Object Into another Plain json Object in TypeScript Angular 2

Tags: json, rest, typescript, angular2-services

Response Body;

```
[
  {
    "professionalId": {
      "cib_code": "30003",
      "thirdPartyId": "RS30004"
    },
    "nationalIdentifier": "984538926",
    "nationalIdType": "SIREN"
  },
  {
    "professionalId": {
      "cib_code": "30003",
      "thirdPartyId": "RS30008"
    },
    "nationalIdentifier": "944316926",
    "nationalIdType": "SIREN"
  }
]
```

By Using Rest Calling from DB getting json Response:

```
this.thirdpartyServices.getThirdparties().subscribe(data=>this.thirdpartyapis$=data);
```

Getting Given Above Json Array Response in `**thirdpartyapis**`  object

but i wanted another object which can contain this data in simple format like

```
[
  {
    "cib_code": "30003",
    "thirdPartyId": "RS30004"
    "nationalIdentifier": "984538926",
    "nationalIdType": "SIREN"
  },
  {
    "cib_code": "30003",
    "thirdPartyId": "RS30008"
    "nationalIdentifier": "944316926",
    "nationalIdType": "SIREN"
  }
]
```

want to map my data in Typscript so that that same object can be use in Html to Display data in Grid table 
Kindly Suggest in angular 2 Typescript

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use destructuring,

```
this.thirdpartyServices.getThirdparties()
  .map(each => {
    let { nationalIdentifier, nationalIdType } = each;
    return {
      ...each.professionalId,
      nationalIdentifier,
      nationalIdType
    };
  })
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.thirdpartyapis$ = data;
  });
```

You may also import 'map' from,

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```